# What would you call the company that 'owns' or oversees a mutual fund or index fund?

Tags: single-word-requests

They don't own it, the investors do, and 'manages' would be inaccurate since the specific people within that company responsible for the fund are listed as the managers.

Edit - More specifically, how would one say xxx mutual fund company ‘oversees’ yyy mutual fund?

Comment: Wikipedia describes [the Vanguard Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Vanguard_Group) as "the largest **provider** of mutual funds [...] in the world."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called *Mutual Fund Company*:

> A mutual fund is a company that brings together money from many people and invests it in stocks, bonds or other assets. The combined holdings of stocks, bonds or other assets the fund owns are known as its portfolio. Each investor in the fund owns shares, which represent a part of these holdings.

([www.sec.gov](http://www.sec.gov))